# Mongo update response says no document updated, but the document is there

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm using MongoDb 2.6.10 and using C# Driver 1.9.2.  The server has a replicaset of two servers.

My documents are of the format.  itemId is unique.

```
{
    "itemID": 2314,
    "Favorites": [1, 24, 26, 34]
}
```

Then I have code to remove a favorite of the form

```
var query = Query.EQ("itemID", itemId);
var result = collection.Update(query, Update.Pull("Favorites", favoriteIdToRemove));
```

After each time, I check that result.DocumentsAffected is equal to 1.  Once in a while, the value comes back as 0.  When I go into MongoDB myself, I can find the document matching the itemID, and I can see the favoriteId that it tried to remove in the array is still there.  result.OK is true, and there's no error information.

What could cause this to fail?

Comment: Typically, the problem is mismatched types between the document and the update request. Can you edit your question to provide a specific reproducible example?

Comment: The problem is it's not consistently reproducible.  In fact, it happens once every couple of days.  That is my exact code, and a sample document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no expert but my guess is write concerns since there are different levels of guarantee for writing to and updating documents in MongoDB. See [Write Concerns](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/core/write-concern/)

So instead of using this [method](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_MongoCollection_Update.htm):

```
MongoCollection.Update Method (IMongoQuery, IMongoUpdate)
```

It might be better to use this [method](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_MongoCollection_Update_4.htm) instead:

```
MongoCollection.Update Method (IMongoQuery, IMongoUpdate, WriteConcern)
```

And specify the WriteConcern to be

```
WriteConcern.WMajority
```

That way the update has the highest guarantee.

Comment: Aren't all write operations done at the primary server?

Comment: Yes, all write operations happen on the primary. However, you can instruct the primary to wait to acknowledge a successful write until N number of secondaries have replicated the write.

Comment: I will try that.  However, if all writes are on the primary, why would changing the write concern affect which version of the document is seen?

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility that when the document already exists and is exactly the same as the previous document, no changes will be needed and therefore, the DocumentsAffected property will be 0. You can see the documentation here: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/WriteResult/#WriteResult. You can see these properties in the Response property of the result.

Comment: Unless my query for the above document is incorrect, I'm certain the document should have removed a favorite.  When I check the document using MongoVUE, it shows the favorite that I tried to remove.

Comment: If you can reliably (or unreliably) create a reproduction, file a SERVER ticket at jira.mongodb.org.